# Java - input JSON to output JSON conversion should be based on JSON schema configuration

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a JSON input and I plan to generate below kind of output JSON. Now I want to generate a JSON schema for each of the use cases described below.
With the help of Java, I would like to dynamically pick the values and prepare the output format as expected.

**Use Case 1**

Input:

```
{
    "First Name": "XX",
    "Middle Name": "",
    "Last Name": "XX",
    "Date of Birth": "11/12/2013",
    "Address": "XXX",
    "Village": "XXX",
    "Pincode": "34234"
    "License Number": "1234567890"
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "First Name": "XX",
    "Middle Name": "",
    "Last Name": "XX",
    "Date of Birth": "11/12/2013",
    "Address": 
    {
        "Village": "XXX",
        "Pincode": "34234"
    }
    "License Number": "1234567890"
}
```

**Use Case 2**

Input:

```
{
    "First Name": "XX",
    "Middle Name": "",
    "Last Name": "XX",
    "Date of Birth": "11/12/2013",
    "Address": "XXX",
    "Village": "XXX",
    "Pincode": "34234"
    "License Number": "1234567890"
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "First Name": "XX",
    "Middle Name": "",
    "Last Name": "XX",
    "Date of Birth": "11/12/2013",
    "Address": 
    {
        "Village": "XXX",
        "Pincode": "34234"
    }
    "License Number": "1234567890"
}
```

Did anyone achieve a similar kind of job?

Answer (score 0):

To get the output that you want you muste create a custom class which has the attributes, like that:

Class `Address`

```
class Address{

    @JsonProperty("Address")
    private String address;

    @JsonProperty("Village")
    private String village;

    @JsonProperty("Pincode")
    private String pinCode;
}
```

Then the Class which contains all `CustomData`, like that:

```
class CustomData {
    @JsonProperty("First Name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("Middle Name")
    private String middleName;

    @JsonProperty("Last Name")
    private String lastName;

    @JsonProperty("Date of Birth")
    private String dateOfBirth;

    private Address address = new Address();

    @JsonProperty("License Number")
    private String licenseNumber;

    // Getters and setters

    @JsonProperty("Address")
    private void setAddress(String val){
        address.setAddress(val);
    }

    @JsonProperty("Village")
    private void setVillage(String val){
        address.setVillage(val);
    }

    @JsonProperty("Pincode")
    private void setPinCode(String val){
        address.setPinCode(val);
    }
}
```

TEST:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Input JSON
        String inputJson = """
                {
                  "First Name": "XX",
                  "Middle Name": "",
                  "Last Name": "XX",
                  "Date of Birth": "11/12/2013",
                  "Address": "XXX",
                  "Village": "XXX",
                  "Pincode": "34234",
                  "License Number": "1234567890"
                }
                """;

        CustomData res = JsonMapper.builder().build().readValue(inputJson, CustomData.class);

        System.out.println(JsonMapper.builder().build().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(res));

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  "First Name" : "XX",
  "Middle Name" : "",
  "Last Name" : "XX",
  "Date of Birth" : "11/12/2013",
  "Address" : {
    "Address" : "XXX",
    "Village" : "XXX",
    "Pincode" : "34234"
  },
  "License Number" : "1234567890"
}
```

Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use JSON libraries with query, transform and restructure capability such as *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"First Name\": \"XX\"," +
    "    \"Middle Name\": \"\"," +
    "    \"Last Name\": \"XX\"," +
    "    \"Date of Birth\": \"11/12/2013\"," +
    "    \"Address\": \"XXX\"," +
    "    \"Village\": \"XXX\"," +
    "    \"Pincode\": \"34234\"," +
    "    \"License Number\": \"1234567890\"" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("field(Address: map(Village, Pincode), Village:, Pincode:)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "First Name" : "XX",
  "Middle Name" : "",
  "Last Name" : "XX",
  "Date of Birth" : "11/12/2013",
  "Address" : {
    "Village" : "XXX",
    "Pincode" : "34234"
  },
  "License Number" : "1234567890"
}
```